# Assesing phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources from code behind wp8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, code-behind

there are some styles declared in the .xaml page of my project inside PhoneApplicationPage.Resources tag.

How can i access these styles in the code behind in windows phone 8

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   <Stlye x:key="Mystlye" TargetType = "Button">
    .....
   </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Now i want to access this Mystlye in codebehind... how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

- To access application level resources (defined in app.xaml / inside `<Application.Resources>`) use :

`Application.Current.Resources["MyResources"]`

- To access application page level resources (defined in thispage.xaml / inside `<ApplicationPage.Resources>`) use :

`Resources["MyResources"]`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var style = Resources["Mystlye"];
```

Comment: make sure to cast to Style

Comment: try following if above one is not working, if working than accept as answer.

var style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["Mystlye"];

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.Style = Application.Current.Resources["Mystlye"] as Style;
```